# Jmeter 5.2.1 in distributed testing mode - cannot see response data in View Results Tree

Tags: jmeter-5.0

Both my master and slave machines are in Linux Environment. When i run the test i'm not able to view the Response data in the View Results Tree Listener.

But when i run the same version in the windows i'm able to view the Response Data in the View Results Tree Listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the following lines in the 'user.properties'file of JMeter 5.0 in the end of the page after'#server.rmi.ssl.disable=false'

jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml

jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true

jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true

jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true

jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true

jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true

And also make changes in the Master Machine 'jmeter.properties' file of the JMeter

## view.results.tree.max_results=500

change to

view.results.tree.max_results=0

This changes will show the Response Data in the View Results tree Listener